# I require help regarding top row of table to be sticky

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[This is my code on github](https://github.com/xeon-zolt/price-table)

This is what I use to make it sticky

```
 var h = document.getElementById("sticky_menu");

var stuck = false;
var stickPoint = getDistance();

function getDistance() {
  var topDist = h.offsetTop;
  return topDist;
}

window.onscroll = function(e) {
  var distance = getDistance() - window.pageYOffset;
  var offset = window.pageYOffset;
  if ( (distance <= 0) && !stuck) {
    h.style.position = 'fixed';
    h.style.top = '0px';
      h.style.paddings ='1px';
      h.style.margins='1px';
    stuck = true;
  } else if (stuck && (offset <= stickPoint)){
    h.style.position = 'static';
    stuck = false;
  }
}
```

[This is what I get after scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCAas.png)
This is my html code where I am using the javascript

```
<tr id="sticky_menu" class="comparison" >
        <th width="24%" class="tl tl2"></th>
        <th width="19%" class="product" style="background:#f96e5b; border-top-left-radius: 5px; border-left:0px;">Exchange Online Plan 1</th>
        <th width="19%" class="product" style="background:#f96e5b;">Office 365 Business Essential </th>
        <th width="19%" class="product" style="background:#f96e5b;">Office 365 &nbsp; &nbsp; Business &nbsp; </th>
        <th width="19%" class="product" style="border-top-right-radius: 5px; border-right:0px; background:#f96e5b;">Office 365 Business Premium</th>
      </tr>
      <tr >
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `position: sticky`?

Comment: where to use position : sticky ?

Comment: That's probably not such a good idea actually, unless you want to use a polyfill.

Comment: i tried using sticky instead of fixed but result was that on scrolling the menu was not being fixed on top of screen

Comment: Provide the working example to help you better. Read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i dont know what polyfill is

Comment: @xeonzolt Google it then.

Comment: added my code github link

Comment: This may be help you https://github.com/jmosbech/StickyTableHeaders

Comment: @ButaniVijay i dont want to use jquery for this thing although i acquired perfect results using jquery i want it either by css or using javascript

Comment: Please check answer. may be help you if you want without jquery

Answer (score 0):

Below Example may be help you if you want only using CSS.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dPixie/byB9d/3/)

[Second Example](https://jsfiddle.net/8mat02dr/)

**HTML :**

```
<section class="">
  <div class="container">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr class="header">
          <th>
           Exchange Online Plan 1
            <div>Exchange Online Plan 1</div>
          </th>
          <th>
           Office 365 Business Essential
            <div>Office 365 Business Essential</div>
          </th>
          <th>
           Office 365 &nbsp; &nbsp; Business &nbsp; 
            <div>Office 365 &nbsp; &nbsp; Business &nbsp; </div>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>align</td>
          <td>left, center, right</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Deprecated in HTML 4.01. Specifies the alignment of a table according to surrounding text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>bgcolor</td>
          <td>rgb(x,x,x), #xxxxxx, colorname</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Deprecated in HTML 4.01. Specifies the background color for a table</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>border</td>
          <td>1,""</td>
          <td>Specifies whether the table cells should have borders or not</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>cellpadding</td>
          <td>pixels</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Specifies the space between the cell wall and the cell content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>cellspacing</td>
          <td>pixels</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Specifies the space between cells</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>frame</td>
          <td>void, above, below, hsides, lhs, rhs, vsides, box, border</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Specifies which parts of the outside borders that should be visible</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>rules</td>
          <td>none, groups, rows, cols, all</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Specifies which parts of the inside borders that should be visible</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>summary</td>
          <td>text</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Specifies a summary of the content of a table</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>width</td>
          <td>pixels, %</td>
          <td>Not supported in HTML5. Specifies the width of a table</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</section>
```

**CSS :**

```
html, body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:100%;
}
section {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding-top: 37px;
  background: #500;
  width:100%;
}
section.positioned {
  position: absolute;
  top:100px;
  left:100px;
  width:800px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #333;
}
.container {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 200px;
}
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  width:100%;
}
td + td {
  border-left:1px solid #eee;
}
td, th {
  border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
  background: #ddd;
  color: #000;
  padding: 10px 25px;
}
th {
  height: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  color: transparent;
  border: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
th div{
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 9px 25px;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: -25px;
  line-height: normal;
  border-left: 1px solid #800;
}
th:first-child div{
  border: none;
}
```

Comment: this example is not working its not making my menu sticky yea but i want my orange colored row to be like that only

Comment: i don't know why are not going for jquery. that is also lightweight

Comment: beacuse i am asked not to use jquery earlier i was using that only

Comment: i think all the problems is due to inline css in td tag but i dont know how to fix it

Comment: tried this but i am getting too much confused how to add this to my css